# AOT - ngc Can't resolve all parameters for Component

Tags: angular, aot, angular-aot

When I build with following JIT instructions `ng build` ; `ng build --prod` everything is ok also when I build for AOT using `--aot` flag, `ng build --aot` The  app works.
But when I try to compile it (AOT) using `ngc` I am getting below error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent in /appname/src/app/home/home.component.ts: (?).
```

This is the HomeComponent class:

```
import {EventManager} from 'app/directives/EventManager.directive';
@Component({
  selector:'home',
  template:`
          ...
    `,
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
    export class HomeComponent  {

      showLoggedBar:Boolean;
      constructor(private _eventManager:EventManager) {

        this._eventManager.showLoggedBar.subscribe((mode)=> {
          if(mode)
          {
            this._eventManager.showBar.emit(true);
            this.showLoggedBar = mode;
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

[EDITED] EventManager :

```
@Injectable()
export class EventManager {
    public showLoggedBar: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    public showLoggedDoBar: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    public showDoBar: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    public showBar:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();
    public dataSearch:EventEmitter<any>= new EventEmitter();
    public updateP:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();
    public updateD:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();
    public detailsAvailable:EventEmitter<any>= new EventEmitter();
    public infoAp:EventEmitter<any>= new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
        this.showBar.emit(true);
    }
}
```

[EDITED] app.module.ts :

```
import{NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {
  LocationStrategy,
  PathLocationStrategy
} from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { routing,  appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {EventManager} from '../app/directives/EventManager.directive';


@NgModule({
  declarations:
    [
      ...
      HomeComponent,
      ...
    ],
  imports:      [BrowserModule,HttpModule,...],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
  providers:[
    ...
    EventManager,
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Do you have any idea of  reason for the error  ?

Comment: Where do you import/provide `eventManager`?

Comment: I guess the question should be where it is provided.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what do you mean by "Where it's provided" ?  I updated my question with EventManager directive

Comment: Hmm... `EventsManager`, `EventManager`, `GlobalEventsManager ` What exactly are you using?

Comment: If you want to inject something, it needs to be provided somewhere `@NgModule({ ..., providers: [{provide: EventManager, useClass: GlobalEventManager}], ... }) export class AppModule {}`

Comment: @yurzui sorry for that :( I use `EventManager`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes  the `EventManager` is provided in `app.module.ts` file as you can see I the question (Edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inject `EventManager`, then you need to provide `EventManager`. Providing `GlobalEventManager` is meaningless.

To inject a `GlobalEventManager` instance, when an `EventManager` is requested, use `useClass`:

```
providers: [{ provide: EventManager, useClass: GlobalEventManager }]
```

if there are components or services that inject `GlobalEventManager`, you can use `useExisting` to avoid two different instances being created:

```
providers: [
    GlobalEventManager, 
    { provide: EventManager, useExisting: GlobalEventManager}
]
```

Comment: I updated `app.module.ts` file as shown in my question but the result still de same

Comment: Hard to tell. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Is there a reason why you store a service in a `directives/Foo.directive` file?

Comment: This is a mistake, its place is in the `services` folder